# Can't install git/perl on ubuntu 16.04 due to broken packages

Tags: 16.04, package-management, lubuntu

This is the error I am getting when I tried to install git on my Lubuntu 16.04.

This is what I got when tried `sudo apt install git`:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
    git : Depends: liberror-perl but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

Then I tried to reinstall perl with `sudo apt install --reinstall perl liberror-perl`:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
    perl : Depends: perl-base (= 5.22.1-9) but 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.2 is to be installed 
           Depends: libperl5.22 (= 5.22.1-9) but 5.22.1-9ubuntu0.2 is to be installed 
           Recommends: rename but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

The following yielded as well no results:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo apt install -f
sudo apt install git
```

Hope somebody can help me to sort it out. Thank you.

Comment: Try `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

Comment: no out put after running the command, tried again the previous installations, but same errors

Answer (score 0):

I go with:

```
apt-get install -y --allow-downgrades perl-base=5.22.1-9
```

Seems to work.